# Issue Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in this column. I don't know how to solve this problem. I would like to refer to this column to apply the same condition in my CSV file, but I receive this error message. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZDpN.png)

`Index(['asset_id,"asset_reference","asset_type","product_warranty_start_date","product_warranty_end_date"'], dtype='object') La colonne 'product_warranty_end_date' n'existe pas dans le DataFrame.`

5 top colone in csv:

```
"asset_id,""asset_reference"",""asset_type"",""product_warranty_start_date"",""product_warranty_end_date"""
"A8f84281ce78c24b38f76f7640d58fa22b3af889f,ZSR204960666,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-30"",""2022-08-30"""
"Ad89164d80210dde87f544cce499cee7ab887b366,ZSR204861880,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-02"",""2022-07-29"""
"Ab4e7c471dbccc3aa82d8d6349445e1a71ebdd2a3,ZSR204661611,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-19"",""2022-07-08"""
"Ac7a63c1b4214f1986eddc7b5e61effe7f507dd35,ZSR204361286,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-26"",""2022-07-24"""
"A6606c6e399f2ab575acebebc0e51ec8c773d9ce4,ZSR201960226,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-15"",""2022-02-10"""
"A84b970dd1aa93082b5116943250ab4192cd3725a,WKS211301180,""Serial Number"",""2021-07-27"",""2051-04-08"""
```

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make a [minimum reproducible example](minimal reproducible example stack overflow) if possible. I would also advice adding the full error traceback

Comment: provide top 5 row of your csv file **by text**

Comment: Looks like you've read the CSV with  just one column and the column name is `'asset_id,"asset_reference","asset_type","product_warranty_start_date","product_warranty_end_date"'`

Comment: And how can i fixe this problem ??

Comment: @AzizeLbaibi You can help us to find a solution by [edit]-ing your question and providing top 5 rows of your CSV file as text.

Comment: Okkk , i did it  , i add top 5 rows in csv

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is to check how the CSV file is generated and fix it there - now there are several problems with the file (e.g. how the values are actually quoted/separated?)

You can try this command to load the file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=r"[,'\"]+", engine="python").iloc[:, 1:-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                    asset_id asset_reference     asset_type product_warranty_start_date product_warranty_end_date
0  A8f84281ce78c24b38f76f7640d58fa22b3af889f    ZSR204960666  Serial Number                  2021-07-30                2022-08-30
1  Ad89164d80210dde87f544cce499cee7ab887b366    ZSR204861880  Serial Number                  2021-07-02                2022-07-29
2  Ab4e7c471dbccc3aa82d8d6349445e1a71ebdd2a3    ZSR204661611  Serial Number                  2021-07-19                2022-07-08
3  Ac7a63c1b4214f1986eddc7b5e61effe7f507dd35    ZSR204361286  Serial Number                  2021-07-26                2022-07-24
4  A6606c6e399f2ab575acebebc0e51ec8c773d9ce4    ZSR201960226  Serial Number                  2021-07-15                2022-02-10
5  A84b970dd1aa93082b5116943250ab4192cd3725a    WKS211301180  Serial Number                  2021-07-27                2051-04-08
```

Comment: I try to use this command, but it doesn't work. I think the problem is in the CSV file. It's originally an XLSM file. I use an online converter to convert the file to CSV. I don't know if that's the source of the problem.

Comment: @AzizeLbaibi Yes, that's the source of the problem. For example, first two column names in your CSV file are defined now like this `"asset_id,""asset_reference"",`. So, where `asset_id` starts and ends? Why there are two `"` in `asset_reference`? etc.

Comment: And how can I fix it? The first thing I should fix is the CSV file, I think, right?

Comment: @AzizeLbaibi Maybe you can try to use `pd.read_excel` to read the Excel file directly.